# Can't change button width in Eclipse (android)

Tags: android, xml, button

Check out Button12s below.  All it is is a button that has the text "GO" but the button is very wide.  I want it just as wide as the text.
It is nested inside a table if that matters.

```
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TableRow1_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/CheckBox25"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="@string/_3x12s" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button12s"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:minWidth="1dp"
                android:onClick="starttimer"
                android:text="@string/_GO" />
```

link to image (I can't embed yet):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFl7.png

Answer (score 0):

android:minWidth="1dp" will cause it to fill the row.

use android:layout_width="wrap_content" to make it tightly fit around the word.

A layout like this might be what you want

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1_1"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  >
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/CheckBox25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="3x12s" />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button12s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="starttimer"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:text="GO" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CheckBox30"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="5reps" />
</TableRow>
```

But I would recommend making your rows bigger than the 25dp that you showed in your sample, as that is a hard button to press.

Comment: No change.  [image](http://oi40.tinypic.com/15hy83n.jpg)      '<Button
                 android:id="@+id/Button12s"
                 android:minHeight="1dp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:onClick="starttimer"
                 android:text="@string/_GO" />'

Comment: weird, I just did the same on my xml file and it did work.  I will have to play with it more.

Comment: If you care, here is the whole file, maybe there is something I'm missing.  [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lyTl-NPskPKjjYDZeCFl6gkTjClh213xdQzFlLaEy18/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I did find if you go to the graphical layout it resets the min width to 64dip for some reason and even if I change it, it just resets to 64dip.

Comment: plz share your values folder too.I copy paste the whole xml file,get many @string/@dimen errors.

Comment: Back at ya:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jtXbf074JnSvJ9bXp3vorjTw7y-4QA7U9ScJRsBkd9s/edit?usp=sharing